# Code assist for javax package in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, code-completion

I'm using Eclipse and I've noticed that I don't get a full list of available methods in my Code Assist whenever I'm using anything under the `javax` package. For example:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.  // this will open up code assist window, but the window only has methods
        // inherited from type Object, not the methods from JFrame
```

I'm using `jdk1.6.0_25` as my JRE, and I ensured my source attachment and javadoc locations are correct for `rt.jar`, and also tried checking everything in Window → Preferences → Java → Editor → Content Assist → Advanced.

I'm pretty new to Eclipse so I'm not sure what I may be doing incorrectly, if there is any other pertinent information that I have left out, let me know and I'll include it.

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you tried pressing the `Ctrl+Space` combo several times to skip various "Template Proposals"?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to cycle through all the proposals to see if any of them would have the methods, but they do not.

Comment: AFAIK code assist will assist anything currently available in the application; I didn't even know it could be turned on/off for specific packages. Are you running under a JRE or JDK?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? Have you tried to create a new workspace with only this one project? What is your OS language for non-unicode programs? `Windows OS, Control panel –> Region and language options –> Advance tab –> Language for non-unicode program –> English (United States)`?

Comment: @Jiri I'm using Indigo Service Release 1. Actually creating a new workspace does rectify the issue and javax code insight becomes available for the new workspace. The Language is English US for non-unicode programs. I guess I'll just make a new workspace and move them my projects over, do you have any idea of what could have caused this so I can avoid doing it in the future? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem, and then I worked it out myself.

In my company classes under these two packages are rarely used (in fact, they are not encouraged). So the pre-installed eclipse just adds them to the filter list.

To fix this, open "Window -> Preferences" and search for "type filters" (in my computer it is in Java-Appearance-Type Filters), and you would see a list of filtered packages, uncheck the "java.awt.*" and "javax.swing.*".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and works perfectly fine in Eclipse Indigo.

`javax.swing.JFrame frame = new javax.swing.JFrame();` frame.//here i get all available methods and everything else i am supposed to...

So, make sure you have the packages imported...
Hope this helps!

Comment: I imported the classes, i.e. for my example above I have import javax.swing.JFrame; The code compiles correctly without error and I can set my JFrame's size and set it to visible, but I just don't receive code assist while I'm doing so, what jre are you using?

Comment: I am using 5_1_10. Hope this helps!